# How to install pandasGUI? Getting OSError in Anaconda prompt

Tags: installation, pip, package, pandasgui

Hello: I am trying to install pandasgui. After several warnings, I get ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError

I have tried a few other ways, but then get CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification error.

Thanks for any suggestions.

I tried installing the package in Anaconda Prompt, using the following:

pip install pandasgui

After several warnings, I get ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError

I have tried a few other ways, but then get CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification error.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. What are "other methods"? Please provide commands and complete error messages

Comment: Here is the full error message: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/fb/6a/93e048f4000c7c4bfdc245714ea6875d2a59926fa02f4b24b6734b592d43/pandasgui-0.2.14.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Comment: I've also tried pip install pandasgui --user

Comment: And pip3 install pandasgui --user

Comment: And this: conda create -n nameofenv python=version
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't post detailed information as comments but edit your question. This way it is easier for others to distinguish between the actual question and informal discussions. Please read [ask].